# howto catch jQuery for multiple links but not all

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to dig into jQuery but would like some feedback on how to do things the best way,

I have a list with items, which each contains a hidden div that should show upon click on it's parent,

```
list
  div:ed item1 with link
    hidden div
  div:ed item2 with link
    hidden div
  ..
```

My current solution is to trace the calling link by it's id and then reusing that ID for showing the correct hidden one:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //jQ should only trigger on links with id="cmLinkINT"
  $("a").click(function() {
    //see if it's a comment request.
    var s = $(this).attr("id");
    if (s.indexOf('cmLink') != -1) {
      //ok, it was a 'show'-link, get the id..
      var j = s.substring(6);
      //ok, now I have the id i want to show (detailsINT)
      return false;
    }    
  });
});
```

What's not clear to me is the best approach,

- Should I use id for requesting a or trace the id of the parent div.
- How to avoid that the code triggers on any link? Class?

**UPDATE**

html example:

```
<div class="unit"> 
  <img class="unitImg" src="imgcache/some.jpg" width="98" height="98" alt="some"/> 
  <div class="unitInfo"> 
    <h1>my unit</h1> 
    <h2>/further..</h2> 
    <p><a href="#" class="showDetails">show details...</a></p> 
    <div style="visibility: hidden;" id="unitDetails2"> 
      <p>peekaboo...</p>
    </div> 
  </div> 
</div> 
<div class="unitGap"></div> 

<div class="unit" ...>
```

Thankful for any feedback,

regards

//t

Comment: `$(this).attr("id")` is a very complicated way of saying `this.id`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you put a class on the anchors that are meant to show the hidden div.

So, your jquery would be (where 'reveal' is the class):

```
$("a.reveal").click(function() {
  $(this).next("div").show();
  return false;
});
```

Or, you could use toggle to show / hide on multiple clicks

```
$("a.reveal").toggle(function() {
  $(this).next("div").show();
  return false;
});
```

Note: I'm assuing that the hidden div is a sibling of the anchor that shows it. Perhaps post your actual markup.

Comment: It's not really clear what the structure of the document looks like.  The OP might need to adjust the traversal if the anchor isn't at the same level as the hidden div.  I do think that using a class to make the semantics of the link explicit is the way to go.

Comment: @tvanfosson - absolutely - I added a note about that, probably just as you were typing.

Comment: @scott, thanks for great input, The link is positioned in a parent-div of the hidden one, so not a sibling. Would very much appriciate furter input.

Comment: In your case, you can use .parent().next()

Comment: I'm going nuts... $(this).hide() works (hiding the href), nothing else, page just scrolls to top. :-|

Comment: fixed scroll to top, but still nothing.. Lost in traversing... Rolling back to id's for now, BIG thanks anyway.

Comment: Just a fyi - .next() gets the next sibling. .next("div") gets the next sibling only if it's a div.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("a[id^=cmLink]").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().find("div[id=^details]").toggle();
});
```

Assuming the div you want to toggle is in the div that also contains the link.

Comment: Nice, but I think the point of the ids was just to associate them.  If that's the case, then you could also just use classes -- which would work for styling purposes as well.

Comment: @tvanfosson: That's right, but this would (very probably) work with the existing markup, and it shows a nice feature of jQuery (start-of-value matches in attributes). Plus, the recommendation to use classes has already been made. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

[Use `.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) to place a handler on the list that looks for clicks on `<a>` elements, then traverse over to the `<div>` using [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) to [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) it:

```
$('#myList').delegate('a','click',function() {
    $(this).next().show();
    return false;
});
```

This assumes the list has the id `myList`. It will handle clicks inside of it on `<a>` elements.

It is a little tough to tell if this is the exactly correct code since you didn't post actual HTML markup. If you post your HTML in the question, I can give a more definite answer.

Comment: Why use .delegate if the markup exists when the handlers are attached? I'm assuing it's not added dynamically of course...

Comment: @ScottE: Dynamically added content is not the only reason to use `.delegate()`. It is used here so that only one handler is assigned (to the list) instead of several (one to each link). Then as you noted, there's the added benefit of having the handler in place if additional links are added to the list.

Comment: I don't think that it creates multiple handlers (separate functions) when using the click method.  It associates the same handler with each matching element.  The difference is only where the handler is attached, not how many handlers there are.

Comment: @tvanfosson: You're right, it doesn't. They share the same function, but jQuery needs to manage them as separate handler entries in `jQuery.cache`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [attribute starts with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector (`[attr="value"]`) here.  You could then find the child div from within the context of the parent div.

```
$('a[id^="cmLink"]').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().find('div').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a more specific selector, for example by giving a specific class (say `cmLink`) to the cm links, and then use a class selector like `$("a.cmLink")`.

Alternatively you can select only the links that are descendants of the `#cm` list, for example `$("#cm > div.item > a")`.

Comment: The latter is more fragile than using a class since it depends on the document structure: change the structure and you introduce a bug.